# Another question on integral domains having special kind of field of fractions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, integral-domain, free-modules

For an integral domain $R$ , let  $Frac(R)$ denote its field of fractions . Then $R$ is embedded in $Frac(R)$  and we can consider $Frac(R)$ as an $R$-module. Can we characterize those integral domains $R$ such that every proper non-zero submodule of the $R$-module $Frac(R)$ is free ?

Obviously since every ideal of $R$ is a $R$-submodule of $Frac(R)$ , so every non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$ is free as an $R$-module , hence $I$ must be principal ideal i.e. $R$ must be a PID . But surely $R=\mathbb Z$ doesn't satisfy the conditions of my question , hence the class of integral domains satisfying my conditions is a strict subclass of PID s .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M\subset Frac(R)$ is a nonzero submodule which is free, then it must be cyclic, since $M\otimes_R Frac(R)=Frac(R)$ is free of rank $1$ over $Frac(R)$.  Or by a more elementary argument, if $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{c}{d}$ are two distinct nonzero elements of $M$ with $a,b,c,d\in R$, then $bcx=ady$, which is a nontrivial relation between $x$ and $y$.  So $x$ and $y$ cannot both be part of a free generating set for $M$, and $M$ cannot be generated freely by more than one element.  So this is equivalent to your previous question: the answer is that $R$ satisfies your condition iff $R$ is a field or a DVR.

Comment: How is $ Frac(R)$ free of rank $1$ ?

Comment: It is free of rank $1$ as a module over itself.

Comment: Ok yeah ; I missed that . Sorry . But why is $M$ tensor (over $R$) $Frac(R)$ is $Frac(R)$ ? And why it follows $M$ is cyclic ? (I don't even know why $M$ would be even finitely generated ) please help

Comment: $M\otimes_R Frac(R)$ is just the localization of $M$ that inverts all nonzero elements of $M$.  That is, it is the set of fractions of the form $m/r$ with $m\in M$ and $r\in R\setminus\{0\}$.  Since $M$ is a nonzero submodule of $Frac(R)$, every such fraction can be considered as an element of $Frac(R)$, and every element of $Frac(R)$ can be written as such a fraction.

Comment: If $M$ is free over $R$, then $M\otimes_R Frac(R)$ is free of the same rank over $Frac(R)$.  So if $M\otimes_R Frac(R)$ has rank $1$ over $Frac(R)$, then $M$ can only have rank $1$ over $R$.

Comment: What would happen if I required that every proper non-zero submodule of the $R$-module $Frac(R)$ is projective ? What can we say about $R$ then ?

Comment: Um hello ... are you there ?

Comment: I suspect the answer is again the same but have not worked out the details.

Comment: Could you please share your thoughts on how you would proceed for the projective case ?

Comment: Prove that $R$ must be a Dedekind domain, and then if $R$ has more than one maximal ideal construct a submodule of $Frac(R)$ which cannot be projective, similar to the example I constructed in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Can you please provide further help to show $R$ is a Dedekind domain ?